# Process - Can not access the File + C# and Write to Csv from Excel

Tags: c#, excel, vba

Is there any equivalent of **FileShare = ReadWrite** while writing from Microsoft Excel using VBA code.

I have a file watcher implemented in a C# application, to start reading the csv file as soon as it's created (I've tried time delay of 1.5 seconds). But sometimes, due to network latency, or volume of data - Excel is still writing to the file, while my application starts reading it.

I open CSV using following code - But still get Acces violation error " “in use by another process” exception" error

```
using (var csv = new FileStream(csvFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `catch` the error and try again later ?

Comment: Assume if there is any way to have C# FileShare.ReadWrite Equivalent in VBA as well, this is can be avoided. I keep polling until the file is released though, something that I want to avoid.